Adding the QuickCheck library to a stack project
I'm trying to add the QuickCheck library to my stack project, I've already added it to build depends on the .cabal file and when I run the stack build command I can see that the library was compiled, however whenever I try to import it on a .hs file it shows a messege like "could not find this module" or "it is not a module in the current program, or in any known package".
I tried to install it using cabal install QuickCheck and that was the result
Resolving dependencies...
Up to date
Warning:
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@ WARNING: Installation might not be completed as desired! @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
The command "cabal install [TARGETS]" doesn't expose libraries.
* You might have wanted to add them as dependencies to your package. In this
case add "QuickCheck" to the build-depends field(s) of your package's .cabal
file.
* You might have wanted to add them to a GHC environment. In this case use
"cabal install --lib QuickCheck". The "--lib" flag is provisional: see
https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/6481 for more information.



When using Stack, you shouldn't have to cabal install any package. Adding it to build-depends should be enough. Various things could be the issue, but it's hard to tell from the current description. Please edit the question so that it provides a minimal reproducible example.

sorry @mark , I just don't what else I could say to help. The only thing i've to add is that I was   able to use some functions from the QuickCheck library on ghci by running the command stack ghci --package QuickCheck, but I still not able to import it on my .hs files

For starters you haven't included any actual Haskell code, or error messages from the Haskell compiler. I would not be surprised at all if you are importing it incorrectly, but that is only a guess with no data.

Please, provide your stack project in a public repository. In advance: You have to edit the file project.yaml. The cabal-file will be generated automatically by stack.

To compile and run a single file you can use cabal, as documented here:
#!/usr/bin/env cabal
{- cabal:
build-depends:
  base,
  QuickCheck
-}

import Test.QuickCheck

main :: IO ()
main = quickCheck (\xs -> reverse xs === (xs :: [Int])

Run with cabal run <filename>.
Otherwise, the first steps you did were what you would do if you were to develop a package. The files containing Haskell code would be part of the package (by mentioning them in an exposed-modules field of the *.cabal file) and stack build/cabal build is how it gets compiled.
